# Ubuntu 18.04 LTS: libQt5Xml.so.5: cannot open shared object file

Tags: 18.04

I didn't used to get this error when running an application launcher in 16.04.  In 16.04 I recall having to install the Qt libraries, but I think that was off the main repository.  Is anyone clued in on what may be going on here with 18.04?

When I launch the "launcher" for an older game I get the following:

> [path to my file] libQt5Xml.so.5: cannot open shared object file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that you simply need to install just [one package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=bionic&arch=any&mode=filename&searchon=contents&keywords=libQt5Xml.so.5):

```
sudo apt-get install libqt5xml5
```

Comment: This was the fix!  I must have been trying to install the wrong library.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

That’s what I initially thought too.  After having I “apt” installed it, the error persisted.  :( Before giving up last night, I wondered if perhaps it was an environmental variable or something along those lines that was all ready set up in 16.04 and not 18.04.

Comment: Regarding the suggestion to install libqt5xml5....That’s what I initially thought too.  After having I “apt” installed it, the error persisted.  :( Before giving up last night, I wondered if perhaps it was an environmental variable or something along those lines that was all ready set up in 16.04 and not 18.04.

Comment: You must _reinstall_ it using _sudo apt install --reinstall libqt5xml5_. Apt believes it is there, but it isn't.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu 18.04 seems to have a problem (at least on my instance) with shared object files that **apt/dpkg** *believes* are installed, but the files are missing.

Use *ldd* to find out which shared object files are missing and reinstall them using apt. In this case, it's missing the package *libqt5xml5*, which you must *reinstall*. Installing will not work, because apt believes it is already installed, but you will find that the file itself is missing.

```
sudo apt install --reinstall libqt5xml5
```

Keep doing this until all the missing shared object files are restored, and the program will launch.

Unfortunately, many of my apps are having the same problem. Something is not correct with the way apt works in Ubuntu 18.04.